# callback function when datatables DOM element has completely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

Hi I was wondering if there was any callback function in datatables that is called after the datatables DOM element has loaded? I know that there are the callbacks fnInitComplete but that does not do what i want. I want to change the width of the "*-List" datatable element.

I thought that when I called this callback function the DOM element would be completely loaded and I could get the width of the element, but when I do this :

```
fnInitComplete: function(oSettings, json) {
  var width = $("#ROI-List").width();
}
```

The width is always 0 meaning that the DOM element hasn't completely loaded.  I am really stuck on this and have tried JQuery to solve this but to no success.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: was a typo changed it

Answer (score 1):

You might want look into the [drawCallback](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback), it's called after each redraw of the DataTable.

```
fnDrawCallback: function (oSeetings) {
  var width = $("#ROI-List").width();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that too but unfortunately it didnt work :(

Comment: What exactly is `$('#ROI-List')`? Can you provide some more information and code about it, maybe in your question posting?